# JsDocs: How do you document methods in a factory function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, documentation, jsdoc

I can't get JsDoc documentation to show up on an object's (`car`) method (`car.drive()`) when the object is created from a factory function `Car()`. This is in VSCode.

Factory Function:

```js
/**
 * Creates car object
 * @param {Sting} model name of
 *
 * @returns {Object} car object
 */
function Car(model) {
  this.model = model;

  /**
   * Makes the car drive
   * @param {String} speed speed of car
   */
  this.drive = (speed) => {
    console.log(`Car is moving at ${speed} miles per hour`);
  };
  return this;
}
```

When I hover my mouse over `car.drive()` it doesn't show the JSDocs. It just displays `Any`.

```js
const car = Car({}); // JsDocs for Car show up here
car.drive() // JsDocs for the drive method don't show up here
```

How can you document `this.drive` in `Car` so you could see the JSDocs on `car.drive()`? Is this possible?

Comment: It is unclear where are you hovering your mouse over `car.drive()`. Is it in VS code?

Comment: Yes in vscode I'm hovering it over 'drive'. I updated the post to add that it's vscode now.

Comment: Hmm it's now working unpredictably. In some files it works, in some it doesn't. It also works when typing but not on hover sometimes. So it seems like it's something with VSC and not the documentation.

Comment: It was working in some files because I initialized it Car differently. see @mylee's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code does recognize JSDoc documentations in JavaScript files.
The only thing missing here to make it work is that `Car` is a constructor and not a function. If you were to initialize a new object of `Car` it would be to use the code

```
var car = new Car({});
car.drive();
```

Look at the documentation for the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator.